# SAP retail functionality in ECC

Tags: sap-erp

I'm currently dabbling with SAP ECC, configuring a solution for an apparel company. I am implementing a solution where inventory is dispatched to retail outlets. Any clues as to which modules and transaction code within those modules I should be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SAP module MM for creating, changing and displaying materials/commodities (e.g. TC MM01, IH09 etc), creating inventories, inventory lists (e.g. TC MI01) and maybe (depending on your/your customer's actual needs) SAP module SD for sales orders, billing and delivery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! So I should still be looking at SD to deal with inventory dispatching to retail outlets (retail outlets that belong to my own company)?

Answer (score 0):

For an apparel company you will likely need:

MM: Material Management
SD: Sales and Distribution
PP: Production Planning
FI: Finance

as a baseline only.  This doesn't take into account any of the necessary methods needed to integrate with suppliers or the customers of the company itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SAP Retail Industry Solution](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Retail/IS-Retail) which supposedly should contain most of the functionality you'd probably need.

It can be installed as an addon module or activated through business function switches (`SFW5` tcode).

[image]

More about switch framework here:

https://sapinsider.wispubs.com/Assets/Articles/2008/October/Industry-Solutions-Are-Now-Integrated-Into-The-SAP-ERP-Core-How-The-Switch-And-Enhancement-Framework